# Making a thumbnail if there exist a link with. jpg or .png extension in Wordpress

Tags: php, image, wordpress, thumbnails, href

Is this possible to make?

I want to make it a thumbnail automatically if there is a link like http://externalsiteorso.com/blablabla.jpg --> make this a thumbnail.

If it's possible, how can I do this?

I have found this, but it's not for `Wordpress`, I guess...

```
$extension = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

// Read source image
if ($extension == ('jpg' || 'jpeg')) {
    $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename); 
    return '1';
} else if ($extension == 'png') {
    $source_image = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
    return '2';
} else {
    return 'error';
}
```

Comment: Hi, try the function here http://trulydotnet.wordpress.com/2010/02/27/post-thumbnails-without-custom-field/

Comment: Hi, thanks, but it says ` syntax error, unexpected '=' `. Besides, it gets the attachments, but I don't have attachments, I have just links in a post... Don't think that will work actually.

Comment: oh ok, but it is worked to me, have another idea i have used from here http://www.sutanaryan.com/automatic-wordpress-thumbnail-without-custom-field-and-featured-image/

Comment: This is weird... This is not working either, but it should work, because for what I can see, it's genuine function. Damn it!

Comment: Are you trying to identify LINKS to images that have been wrapped inside <a href=... then convert them to <img src=... ? Or have I got that wrong?

Comment: Well, yeah... I was looking at that right now and I saw your comment and EUREKA. That's why it's not working. They are not `<img>` tags (I thought it was), but just links with .jpg extension in an anchor indeed, going to the image. I will change my question.